# Replacing a list value with a string

Tags: r, string, list, gsub

I have data as follows:

```
dat <- list(c(0, 25, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 1e+06))
```

I am simply trying to replace the value `1000000` with the string value `"Infinity"`. Even though:

```
dat[1]
# [[1]]
# [1]       0      25     100     250     500    1000 1000000

dat[[1]

# [1]       0      25     100     250     500    1000 1000000
```

If I try:

```
gsub(1000000, "Infinity", dat[[1]])
```

Nothing happens. Why does nothing happen in this case and what would be the right way to do this?

Comment: Note that R uses `Inf` as a numerical value for infinity, which would avoid converting the whole column to `character`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use `gsub`, you need to set `fixed = TRUE`.

```
dat <- list(c(0, 25, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 1e+06))

dat[[1]] <- gsub(1000000, "Infinity", dat[[1]], fixed = T)

dat
[[1]]
[1] "0"        "25"       "100"      "250"      "500"      "1000"    
[7] "Infinity"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the RHS `gsub` call to a LHS variable, probably the vector itself inside the list.  But, given that your initial vector contains numerical values, you should instead use equality here:

```r
dat[[1]][dat[[1]] == 1000000] <- "Infinity"
dat

[[1]]
[1] "0" "25" "100" "250" "500" "1000" "Infinity"
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `rapply`. `rapply` is a recursive version of lapply with flexibility in how the result is structured (how = ".."). See `?rapply`

```
rapply(dat,function(x) ifelse(x==1000000,"Infinity",x), how = "replace")
```

```
[[1]]
[1] "0"        "25"       "100"      "250"      "500"      "1000"     "Infinity"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `replace` and `lapply` (though `rapply` is the better choice over `lapply`):

```
lapply(dat, function(x) replace(x, x == 1000000, "Infinity"))
```

**Output**

```
[[1]]
[1] "0"        "25"       "100"      "250"      "500"      "1000"     "Infinity"
```